# Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship error with EF core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am not sure why I am getting this error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The relationship from 'Insured' to 'Quote.Insureds' with foreign key properties {'InsuredID' : string} cannot target the primary key {'InsuredID' : string, 'ProducerID' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.'

I am trying to configure two keys in the Quote model, one for my Insured model and one for my Producer. I attempted to only have one key before and just use foreign keys but that didnt work.

```
 public class Producer 
    {
        [Key]
        public string ProducerID { get; set;  }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
```

```
public class Insured
    {
        [Key]
        public string InsuredID { get; set; }
        public string NamedInsured { get; set; }
        public string Address1 {get; set;}
```

```
public class Quote
    {
        public string InsuredID { get; set; }
        public string ProducerID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProducerID")]
        public IList<Producer> Producers { get; set; }   
        [ForeignKey("InsuredID")]
        public IList<Insured> Insureds { get; set; }
```

In my DB context:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Quote>().HasKey(q => new { q.InsuredID , q.ProducerID});
```

Comment: Foreign Key and collection navigation property inside one and the same object are mutually exclusive.  See [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to reference an array with a key
It needs to be an object rather than a collection.

```
public class Quote
{
    public string InsuredID { get; set; }
    public string ProducerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProducerID")]
    public Producer Producer { get; set; }   
    [ForeignKey("InsuredID")]
    public Insured Insured { get; set; }
}
```